# "Cannot convert from 'std::ofstream {aka std::basic_ofstream<char>}' to bool" error in return

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I've written this code

```
ofstream f(<namefile>);

f.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&ins.num_dip),
    sizeof(ins.num_dip));

f.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(ins.dip),
    ins.num_dip * sizeof(char));

return f;
```

but I don't understand where I'm wrong, can you help?

Comment: You'd need to write `static_cast<bool>(f)`, because `std::ofstream`'s conversion to `bool` is `explicit`.

Comment: what is the type of ins.num_dip and ins.dip? This question is incomplete.

Comment: This is just a snippet of code in a vacuum. Where is it being run? In what context? Which of those two language versions are you actually using? Present your [mcve].

Comment: @Justin Don't provide answers in comments thanks

Comment: @Justin alternatively, you can write `return f.good();` or `return !f.fail();` (`ofstream::operator bool()` returns `!fail()`)

Answer (score 2):

The conversion operator which allows converting `std::ostream` (and other `std` streams) to `bool` is explicit, which means it can only be used for explicit casts and for contextual conversions to bool (such as inside conditions). Returning a boolean is not a contextual conversion to bool, so the cast would have be to explicit:

```
return static_cast<bool>(f);
```

You can also use the appropriate getter instead of the cast:

```
return !f.fail();
```